# Best Option to Search with autocomplete with suggestions?

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, solr, nlp

I hope to develop a search function like google for my website with auto complete. scenarios are below

- User Can input keywords with spelling mistakes and get the correct suggestion only for items in our site
- the user must get autocomplete suggestions if they are typing a word
- Must be able to input keywords and to train a model for suggestions

After little research, i found below products are capable of doing such a task

- Apache Solr
- Elasticsearch

can someone explain about these two services and tell me what can be developed with a minimum development effort and maximum efficiency? and if there are any other products match the scenario mentions above suggest me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch offers these features in the form of Suggesters (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html).

- The Term-Suggester is able to suggest other terms by edit-distance. Meaning it can 'fix' typos.
- The Phrase-Suggester is more complex, but essentially suggests the 'fixed' phrase.
- The Completion-Suggester is basically for autocompletion.

They all rely on their indexed data. Basically you index real/correct search phrases on which these suggesters will work. The cool thing is that when you add new search phrases to these indexes, the 'model' will be updated automatically. Meaning you can expand the capabilities over time.

Unfortunately, I have not yet used these, so I can't give you advice/tips on how to do it. Try referring to the documentation - it is usually quite good. However, I imagine this task could be a bit difficult, if you have no idea of Elasticsearch yet. So you might want to read the 'Getting Started'.

As for Solr: I don't know how you'd do it there. I just know that it uses the same underlying text search engine - [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). So I expect they do not differ much in terms of functionality.